# Powershell script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a similar problem,i want to install Ciscoemail on Win 7 but it simply didnt work.I have successfully installed it on Win XP via Group Policy with this script

```
md c:\ciscoemail

if not exist c:\ciscoemail\CiscoEmailSecurity_7-2-0-039.exe copy \\Domain Name\cisco\CiscoEmailSecurity_7-2-0-039.exe c:\ciscoemail /Y
if not exist c:\ciscoemail\response_file.iss copy \\Domain Name\cisco\response_file.iss c:\ciscoemail /Y
del c:\ciscoemail\setup.log /f /q

if not exist C:\PROGRA~2\Cisco\CISCOI~1\CISCOE~1.DLL c:\ciscoemail\CiscoEmailSecurity_7-2-0-039.exe /s /v /qn /f1"c:\ciscoemail\response_file.iss"
```

Can someone please assist with turning the code to Powershell code.
The simple steps are :

1. Make directory to Local c drive.
2. check if the ciscoemail exists on the local c drive.
3. create folder if it does not exist and copy ciscoemail\CiscoEmailSecurity_7-2-0-039.exe  and ciscoemail\response_file.iss to c drive
4. .exe (installation file)

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a code translation service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129362/143302)

Answer (score 0):

The basic translation:

```
# In PowerShell, md is an alias to mkdir which 
# is a function for creating folders
$folder = md c:\ciscoemail

# copy is an alias for Copy-Item
if( -not(Test-Path -Path c:\ciscoemail\CiscoEmailSecurity_7-2-0-039.exe))
{
    copy -Path \\Domain Name\cisco\CiscoEmailSecurity_7-2-0-039.exe -Destination $folder.FullName
}

if( -not(Test-Path -Path c:\ciscoemail\response_file.iss))
{
    copy -Path \\Domain Name\cisco\response_file.iss -Destination $folder.FullName
}

if( Test-Path -Path c:\ciscoemail\setup.log )
{
    # del is an alias to Remove-Item
    del -Path c:\ciscoemail\setup.log -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
}        

if( -not(Test-Path -Path "C:\PROGRA~2\Cisco\CISCOI~1\CISCOE~1.DLL"))
{
    c:\ciscoemail\CiscoEmailSecurity_7-2-0-039.exe /s /v /qn /f1"c:\ciscoemail\response_file.iss"
}
```

Comment: What about if I want to sign it with digital certificate so that every Win7 machine will recognise and trust the installation script?

Comment: Sign your scripts and set the execution policy of your clients to AllSigned.

Comment: Sure, see the about_Signing topic, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347649.aspx